# Natural isomorphism of homology theories that factors through Comp

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology

**Warning:** I suspect that the answer to my following question is negative in this generality, however it seemed the best way to express what kind of results I am looking for (see my last point).

Suppose we have two homology theories on the same category, i.e. two covariant functors $$h_*, h_*' \colon \mathcal{L} \to \mathsf{Ab}$$ that factor through the category of chain complexes $\mathsf{Comp}$,i.e. $$h_*=H_*(C_{\bullet}) \text{ and } h_*'=H_*(C_{\bullet}'),$$ where $C_{\bullet}, C_{\bullet}' \colon \mathcal{L} \to \mathsf{Comp}$ are covariant functors. Suppose that $h_*$ and $h_*'$ are naturally isomorphic via a natural transformation $$\Phi_* \colon h_* \to h_*'.$$

My question is the following:

Can one recover information/any relations between the chain complex functors $C_{\bullet}, C_{\bullet}'$? Or more concretely:

Does there exist a natural isomorphism $$\Psi_{\bullet} \colon C_{\bullet} \to C_{\bullet}'$$ that coincides with $\Phi_*$ in homology?

(**Edit:** This does not hold in general, see comments below)

**New question:** Does there exist a natural chain map $\Psi_{\bullet}\colon C_{\bullet} \to C_{\bullet}'$ that agrees with $\Phi_*$ in homology?

Ordinary homology theories in the sense of Eilenberg-Steenrod together with the uniqueness result of such theories seem to be a good starting point, but I was not able to find anything useful (probably due to my lack of knowledge in (axiomatic) homology theory...).

Comment: The answer is clearly no : it suffices that there be natural maps $f:C\to C', g: C'\to C$ such that $f\circ g$ qnd $g\circ f$ are (pointwise) homotopic to the identity (of the relevant complex) for there to be a natural isomorphism between the homologies. Even less should suffice

Comment: @Max I'm afraid that I'm missing your point: 
I agree, a natural chain equivalence between $\mathsf{C}_{\bullet}$ and $\mathsf{C}_{\bullet}'$ induces a natural isomorphism in homology, but how does that answer my question with a 'no'?

Comment: Well there are many chain-homotopic complexes that aren't isomorphic

Comment: @Max you are right, thanks. I editet the question to include the isomorphic bit as an hypothesis.

Comment: I don't think that's the right modification (requiring an existing isomorphism seems artificial, and in concrete situations such as, say singular and cellular homologies, will very rarely happen). Moreover, there are again clear counterexamples (perhaps not as clear as the ones above - if you confirm that that's what you want to ask I can add an answer with some counterexample) I would rather ask whether it's always induced by *some* morphism (but perhaps you already know the answer to that)

Comment: @max no of course, you are right! In my example equivariant homology and homology with local coefficients pop up, where it "just so happens" to be the case that both are chain isomorphic.. Well yes, if the induced morphism is natural then that would solve my original problem (and no, I do not know the answer to that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "natural" bit here is a red herring, and seeing that it's not relevant makes the question a lot easier.

Indeed at this level of generality ($\mathcal{L}$ an arbitrary category) we can let functors "be anything" and "natural" sort of loses its point. Indeed, it suffices to take $\mathcal{L}$ to be the discrete category on one object.

At that point, a functor $\mathcal{L}\to \mathsf{Comp}$ is just the choice of a complex, and $\mathcal{L}\to \mathbf{Ab}$ just the choice of an abelian group.

A natural isomorphism (or more generally transformation) is then just an isomorphism (or more generally morphism). Hence at this level of generality, a special case of your question becomes :

> If I have an isomorphism between the homologies of two complexes, is this isomorphism induced by some (iso)morphism of complexes ?

The answer to that is clearly no. For instance consider a complex $\mathsf{C}$ with only $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ in position $0$ and $0$'s elsewhere, and $\mathsf{C'}$with $\mathbb{Z}$ in position $-1$ and $0$, the map $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ being multiplication by $2$ . Then the homologies of both complexes are isomorphic (they're $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ in position $0$, and $0$ elsewhere); but there is no nontrivial morphism $\mathsf{C\to C'}$, hence no morphism that could induce the isomorphism in homology.

In fact this isn't category-dependent (you might argue that I chose a dummy category):  for any category $\mathcal{L}$, you can "model" this situation by picking constant functors, and the result will be the same; therefore if you want to add some conditions to change the answer to "yes", then the conditions will not only be on $\mathcal{L}$ but also on the functors you have, e.g. respect products or whatever. But that would be another question, and right now I don't have examples of natural (non trivial) constraints one could add on the functors to have a positive answer.

The moral here is that the functor $H_* : \mathsf{Comp}\to \mathbf{Ab}$ is very very far from being full.

Comment: Thanks, as I suspected, at this level of generality the answer is negative...